# Printing Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I don't know how to print this :

[image]

in this format :

```
destroyer: 
192.23.30.40 => 2,
192.23.30.41 => 1,
192.23.30.42 => 1
```

can someone do it ?

Comment: Show your current `PrintDict` method. What is going wrong ? Where did you stop ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **LINQ** to get a collection of strings representing your entries and join them:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dictAndNames.Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} => {pair.Value}")));
```

Explained:

```
// Method to take all the pairs and format them as the string you like:
Func<KeyValuePair<string, int>, string> selector = 
     pair => $"{pair.Key} => {pair.Value}";

// Convert all the elements in the dictionary:
var values = dictAndNames.Select(selector);

// Join them with the separator you like (you can also use Environment.NewLine):
var joined = string.Join(", ", values);

// Print:
Console.WriteLine(joined);
```

If you are not using **C# 6** as pointed out, you can simply replace the string interpolation with a `string.Format` invocation:

```
string.Format("{0} => {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value)
```

Comment: Note - The use of `$` (string interpolation) will work only in c# 6.0 and above

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

Loop over the **`KeyValuePair`** in the dictionary **`dictAndNames`**

```
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in dictAndNames)
   {
      Console.Write(item.Key+"=>" + item.Value.ToString());               
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

mmm both of the ways does not work , i need to print "destroyer" also , but destroey must be printed from the dictionary, when i try

```
`foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in dictAndNames)
```

{
      Console.Write(item.Key+"=>" + item.Value.ToString());
   }  `

there is an error that cant convert, and when i try this

```
`Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dictAndNames.Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} => {pair.Value}")));`
```

console says : `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] => System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]`

Comment: this should be a comment on answer